# What is a statistically rigorous model?

Tags: computational-statistics

Is there a formal definition for a model or methodology being statistically rigorous?
I've seen the term often used in research papers but I've never fully understood what makes the model or method statistically rigorous.
I've mostly been seeing them in the context of mathematical models for physical processes such as Computational Fluid Dynamics (CFD) models.

Comment: I think you will need to supply a reference or--better yet--a quotation and an explanation of the context.  Otherwise the answers are likely to be a matter of guesswork and opinion.